# Can Apache beam support Parallel Sorting?

Tags: sorting, apache-spark, apache-beam

Could you please tell me if I can achieve parallel sorting using Apache beam? For the documentation it is given that Apache Beam can sort using a single machine. Is there any way to achieve parallel sorting?

Comment: What is the use case you have for sorting? Generally we have found that, every time someone tries to solve a problem using a global sort, it turns out that there is a better way to solve the problem without using a global sort :)

Comment: Here is the flow sequence we use and not sure at what point and how we can achieve sorting. We have a datastructure in the format KV<ID,Employee Object>. We do a group by Key and produce output KV<ID, Iterable<Employee>>. We do a groupbykey since for each and every ID we create file. Sorting requirement is in the property data in the Employee object such as ID, Age, Designation,....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ah, so you're doing merely a per-key sort, not a global sort. Please use [the SortValues transform](https://beam.apache.org/documentation/sdks/java-extensions/#example-usage-of-sortvalues). Each individual key will be sorted using a single machine, but I presume that the amount of data you have *per key* is not that big. Please let me know if that's not the case and if after trying this transform you find that it performs unacceptably.

Comment: Sorting based on multiple fields and not single ID. EmployeeID, Name, Age, Position etc.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that you want to sort each Iterable<Employee> inside your KV<ID, Iterable<Employee>>?

Comment: 1) Correct. In Addition to sorting by ID, Sorting needs to be implemented for many other fields inside the employee object. such as "select * from employee order by id,age,salary,postion,Address desc".2)  For each and every employee id we will create files. so we are maintaining the KV<EmployeeId, Iterable<Employee Object>>.

Comment: Excellent. How many employees are there for each id max? Can you use the standard Java Collections.sort() function?

Comment: Yes we can use the same. For each and every ID can have a million records as we are dealing with files in GB.